# Java - Register all classes annotated with @MyAnnotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, aop, guice

I have an annotation `@MyAnnotation` and I can annotate any type (class) with it. Then I have a class called `AnnotatedClassRegister` and I would like it to register all classes annotated with `@MyAnnotation` so I can access them later. And I'd like to register these classes automatically upon creation of the `AnnotatedClassRegister` if possible, and most importantly before the annotated classes are instantiated.

I have AspectJ and Guice at my disposal. The only solution I came up with so far is to use Guice to inject a singleton instance of the `AnnotatedClassRegister` to an aspect, which searches for all classes annotated with `@MyAnnotation` and it adds the code needed to register such class in its constructor. The downside of this solution is that I need to instantiate every annotated class in order for the code added by AOP to be actually run, therefore I cannot utilize lazy instantiation of these classes.

Simplified pseudo-code example of my solution:

```
// This is the class where annotated types are registered
public class AnnotatedClassRegister {
    public void registerClass(Class<?> clz) {
        ...
    }
}

// This is the aspect which adds registration code to constructors of annotated
// classes
public aspect AutomaticRegistrationAspect {

    @Inject
    AnnotatedClassRegister register;

    pointcutWhichPicksConstructorsOfAnnotatedClasses(Object annotatedType) : 
            execution(/* Pointcut definition */) && args(this)

    after(Object annotatedType) :
            pointcutWhichPicksConstructorsOfAnnotatedClasses(annotatedType) {

        // registering the class of object whose constructor was picked 
        // by the pointcut
        register.registerClass(annotatedType.getClass())
    }
}
```

What approach should I use to address this problem? Is there any simple way to get all such annotated classes in classpath via reflection so I wouldn't need to use AOP at all? Or any other solution?

Any ideas are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be runtime or can you make the list at compile time?

Comment: It does have to be at runtime because it's a framework feature. Users of the framework will use the annotation to annotate their classes and the framework should do all the dirty work to register them when the application is started.

Comment: Okay, but the assembly could still be done at compile time, as long as the framework knows how to find it at runtime, right?

Comment: Well, JPA implementations do it at runtime on annotated classes with @Entity and such. Do they use a common standard way to retrieve all annotated classes or do they check the entire classloader for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible:

1. Get all paths in a classpath. Parse `System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path", null)` to get all paths.
2. Use `ClassLoader.getResources(path)` to get all resources and check for classes: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4831

Comment: The code snippet you posted helped me and it seems like what I've been looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Broken link (May/2017)

Answer (score 4):

It isn't simple that much is sure, but I'd do it in a Pure Java way:

- Get your application's Jar location from the classpath
- Create a JarFile object with this location, iterate over the entries
- for every entry that ends with `.class` do a `Class.forName()` to get the Class object
- read the annotation by reflection. If it's present, store the class in a List or Set

Aspects won't help you there, because aspects only work on code that's actually executed.

But [annotation processing](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-1.html) may be an Option, create a Processor that records all annotated classes and creates a class that provides a List of these classes

Comment: Thanks for Your answer! But what if I don't have a jar file? It's a web application running on Tomcat in exploded `war` directory. I'll look into annotation processing meanwhile..

Comment: @eQui in that case use Peter's answer, which is a slight variation of mine that will also work with exploded war files (or use annotation processing)

Comment: Annotation Processing looks like it would do what I want but it needs me to specify which classes to process and that I don't know until runtime.. I have found this [nice article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html) which explains how the processing can be run programatically from java code, but how can I process all classes in the web application's classpath?

Comment: @eQui *but it needs me to specify which classes to process* Nope. The only thing you need to know is which annotation to look for. You can't run annotation processing from the web container. apt works on sources, not compiled classes, it's part of the build process.

Comment: +1 for broadening my horizons because I didn't know that such a thing as annotation processing even existed. I would give another +1 for your explanations but I can't :) Anyway, I got it working nicely thanks to the code snippet @Peter has posted. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your `AnnotatedClassRegister.registerClass()` doesn't have to be called immediately at `AnnotatedClassRegister` creation time, but it could wait until a class is first instantiated, then I would consider using a Guice `TypeListener`, registered with a `Matcher` that checks if a class is annotated with `@MyAnnotation`.

That way, you don't need to search for all those classes, they will be registered just before being used. Note that this will work only for classes that get instantiated by Guice.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `staticinitialization()` pointcut in AspectJ and amend classes to your register as they are loaded, like so:

```java
after() : staticinitialization(@MyAnnotation *) {
    register.registerClass(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
}
```

Piece of cake, very simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ClassGraph`](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) package like so:

Java:

```
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph().enableAnnotationInfo().scan()) {
  for (ClassInfo classInfo = scanResult.getClassesWithAnnotation(classOf[MyAnnotation].getName()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("classInfo = %s", classInfo.getName()));
  }
}
```

Scala:

```
Using(new ClassGraph().enableAnnotationInfo.scan) { scanResult =>
  for (classInfo <- scanResult.getClassesWithAnnotation(classOf[MyAnnotation].getName).asScala) {
    println(s"classInfo = ${classInfo.getName}")
  }
}
```